# negation equivalence

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have this exercise:

Write a script, which uses if-then-else-fi and accept sequence of parameters -a and -b with values "true" and "false", while for every pair writes negation of expression -a <=> -b,

Example:

```
-a       -b        writes

true     true      false

true     false     true

false    true      true

false    false     false
```

For example:

```
./script -a false -b false -a true -b true
```

writes:

```
true

false
```

My question is how to make script accept parameters?

I just struggle with the input. Everything else should be fine.

Comment: Is this a shell script?  Bash?  Python?  Something else?

Comment: You may want to check out the [`getopts` tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Comment: Yes, it is bash

Comment: Also, your spec is missing some behavior—what does `./script -a false -a false` do? Or `./script -a false -b false -a true`?

Comment: That enters boolean values into the script

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ $( $2 or 0 ) xor $( $4 or 0 ) ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Explanation:

Based on the logic table that is an XOR operation so using `$2` and `$4` (the second and fourth arguments which have the data we need to do this operation)
of course this doesn't account for when someone switches `-a` and `-b`.

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying to get it to process multiple sets. for that you're going to need a for loop.

Comment: Is this intended to be pseudo-code? The shell certainly does not handle this the way you think it does. Hint: it always echoes true